Is there a `ColorScheme.fromSeed` equivalent in Jetpack Compose (Android or Multiplatform) similar to Flutter’s `ColorScheme.fromSeed`?
I'm working with Jetpack Compose on Android (or Compose Multiplatform) and am looking for a way to generate a full color scheme based on a single seed color, similar to how Flutter’s ColorScheme.fromSeed works.
In Flutter, ColorScheme.fromSeed takes a single seed color and generates a cohesive set of colors for primary, secondary, background, error, etc., which are all harmonized and suitable for both light and dark themes according to Material Design guidelines.
Does Jetpack Compose offer a similar built-in function to generate a complete color scheme from a seed color? Alternatively, is there a library that provides this functionality, or any recommended approach to implement a similar feature in Compose?

Is the goal to generate the theme dynamically on runtime?

Otherwise the official Material Theme Builder can be used to generate an entire theme from a given color.

I found a library called MaterialKolor that provides similar functionality to Flutter’s ColorScheme.fromSeed for Jetpack Compose. MaterialKolor generates Material Design color schemes based on a single seed color, creating primary, secondary, background, and other colors while ensuring good contrast and visual harmony.
MaterialKolor uses Material Design’s color algorithms to derive tones and shades, allowing you to easily create cohesive color schemes that adapt to both light and dark themes. Here’s a quick example from the library's documentation on how to use it:
@Composable
fun MyTheme(
    seedColor: Color,
    useDarkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = rememberDynamicColorScheme(seedColor, useDarkTheme)

    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colorScheme.toMaterialColors(),
        content = content
    )
}

